# getting null value while parsing json data in android

Tags: android, json

i am trying to parse json data in android app i am able to get title of the book and author but i am not able to parse publisher i am getting null value at publisher

```
   "kind":"books#volumes",
       "totalItems":997,
       "items":[  
          {  
             "kind":"books#volume",
             "id":"g3hAdK1IBkYC",
             "etag":"o+CdTUx3mkQ",
             "selfLink":"https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes/g3hAdK1IBkYC",
             "volumeInfo":{  
                "title":"Professional Android 4 Application Development",
                "authors":[  
                   "Reto Meier"
                ],
                "publisher":"John Wiley & Sons",
                "publishedDate":"2012-04-05",
}
```

here is the java code written for Json

```
 JSONObject root = new JSONObject(jsonResponse);
            JSONArray itemsArray = root.optJSONArray("items");
            for (int i=0;i<itemsArray.length();i++){

                JSONObject singleItem = itemsArray.getJSONObject(i);


                JSONObject volumeInfo = singleItem.getJSONObject("volumeInfo");
                String title = volumeInfo.getString("title");
                Log.i("title_book",title);

                String author = volumeInfo.getString("authors");
                Log.i("author_book",author);
                String publisher = singleItem.getString("publisher");
                Log.i("publisher_book",publisher);
```

Comment: Your json is not well formatted, try to format it, you should be able to traverse it

Comment: what exactlyare you trying to saying ? my json is not formatted in the question or the java code that i have written

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `publisher` is contained by `volumeInfo`. Try:

```
String publisher = volumeInfo.getString("publisher");
```